# estimation of big comparison task

Tags: java, io, comparison, cpu-usage, virtual-memory

I have a programming task from the university which requires finding shared strings of a constant length by comparing of hundreds of files (good files and bad files, smaller than one megabyte) byte by byte.

Suppose I'm going for a total coverage of the comparisons, and I actually compare each file to other files, is it possible to actually complete this task within a few minutes?

I've tried the naive algorithm and I've been improving on it for several days now, and I can't seem to drop under a few hours.

What I did so far:

### CPU:

I've locally bench-marked different comparisons and buffer sizes to see which fits my needs best.

I don't keep the signature itself, only a reference to it (via a boolean array that has the same size of the file - also helps me not to compare again an index that has been ruled out).

I'm currently installing callable comparison tasks into the system with hope it won't create too much overhead or synchronization issues.

### Virtual Memory:

I'm determining buffer sizes according to the free memory available (`System.freeMemory()` - about 2GB after manually specifying it) to prevent thrashing and I've settled for a reasonable (to my view) trade-off between information saved per file

### Algorithm:

I try and compare only a subset of the bytes in suspicious location after a static analysis of the files' structures (JAR files, I didn't go into bytecode, because I have no idea how to extrapolate relevance from bytecode - I only compare the "classes.dex").

---

Given that this must be a common task, am I missing something very obvious? I've been told that hashing the signatures can be faster, but I doubt that's faster than waiting for the comparisons to end and storing them later, via the references (this is very fast once the comparisons themselves, which are the bottleneck, ends). To me hashing seems like a big VM hogging risk.

It was told that this should run within "Reasonable time" and the aim is to find the best (smallest) superset (covers most bad files and no good files) of the files (or close to it). It seems to me that I'm way off after hearing some people that claim to have completed it.

If more information is needed please ask, and I'll edit it into the post.

---

I am planning on using [this](http://concurrent-trees.googlecode.com/svn/concurrent-trees/javadoc/apidocs/com/googlecode/concurrenttrees/radixinverted/ConcurrentInvertedRadixTree.html) implementation of a Trie, in case I forget to update this, I hope you who runs into this can utilize it (or others in this project) for your needs!

Comment: don't know whether I got it right, but what about extracting relevant strings from each file one by one and putting that in to some database index like `[string] | [file]`. Afterwards you may count on distinct strings in the DB and find all relevant files listed? That would end up in a small memory footprint and you are not running in to combinatoric explosion?

Comment: I have DB integrated but the run-time is my main concern.

The Trie idea is very interesting and seems to be the right approach. I'll test it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cover all Strings, what you are after is a `trie`. It is a tree where each node would be a byte of one of your Strings. The final node would report how many times the String appears.

If you have "Dog", "Dad", "Dod", "Dog", you end with something like

```
 D
 | -------
 |       |
 a       o-------
 |       |      |
 |       |      |
 d(1)    d(1)   g(2)
```

Since the Strings are of fixed lenght `n`, you will have at max 256^i nodes by each level i, so the total would be 256^0 + 256^1 + ... + 256^n (it is an upper limit) nodes.

Comment: Very interesting! Reminds me of the Lempel-Ziv encoding which slipped my mind! I'll look into it and try to compile a solution.

Comment: aren't you all too academic on that or am I missing something? This is the usual search engine problem. Google is also not "SEARCHING FOR POSSIBLE TERMS" but indexing all relevant terms and searching for afterwards. Leave the search algorithm to an unique index key column in your database, it will do its job. In the case above, all the math is irrelevant, since there are exactly two (2) terms: Dog and Dad. These get an unique index and in a second relation all occurrences (filenames) are listed. To "find" all files with dog should be some microseconds and a `sigh...`from your DB engine...

Comment: I'm searching for byte streaks, so I'm not sure how what you suggest solves the problem.

By no means are they meaningful, and the Trie suggestion was the right approach.

Comment: @AxelAmthor You are missing a lot of things. 1) Google needs to store the terms, the OP does not. Also, the OP does not want to know how many files have the String `x` (you can do that with `grep`), read the requirements more carefully. 2) A good memory structure is way faster than DBs (no HD access, which is SLOW). and that is what the OP is requiring. 3) Having an idea of how does your algorithm behave (both in memory requirements and in computation time) should be a *must* before getting to implement it, otherwise you will lose lots of time "improving" something that does not work.

Comment: @SJuan76 Thought so, forget about my comments if they aren't useful.